# It is possible to use aggregate function when inserting data in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, rdfs

I have the following query which aims to prevent the insertion in a named graph when the amount of triples is of a given number, e.g., 5.

I tried to reproduce the example showed [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData) where the insertion of data is possible but I need to use the same named graph and, most important an aggregate function, i.e., COUNT.

```
INSERT 
  { 
    GRAPH <http://example/g1> { ?s ?p ?o } 
  }
WHERE
  { 
  GRAPH  <http://example/g1>
   { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER ( COUNT(?p) < 5)
   } 
}
```

Jena Fuseki raises the following error:

```
 Aggregate expression not legal at this point
```

Comment: RDF is a set of triples. Any order would have to be done in terms of IDs introduced by yourself and then indeed the usage of `ORDER BY` in the SPARQL query is required. Anything else would be some implementation dependent ordering with no guarantees.

Comment: You changed the **whole question**! Why did you do this? My comment doesn't make any sense now...

Comment: Your comment helped me to better understand the problem

Comment: Ok, but next time please open a new question then. Other people might need help for the same problem which now doesn't exists anymore here.

Comment: AKSW I didn't see the original but wasn't that the point of your comment though? It would be different if the original question was answerable....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible:

```
INSERT 
  { 
    GRAPH <http://example/g2> { ?s ?p ?o } 
  }
WHERE
{ 
  GRAPH <http://example/g1> {
    ?s ?p ?o .           # select all triples
    { SELECT ?s          # do a check for the selected subject
      WHERE { GRAPH <http://example/g1> { ?s ?p ?o } }
      GROUP BY ?s            # count properties per subject
      HAVING (COUNT(?p) < 5) # only subjects with less than 5 properties 
    }
  }
}
```

First of all, aggregate operators cannot be placed inside a `FILTER` clause, to use them as a conditional you have to put them in a `HAVING` clause instead.

Furthermore since you want to count properties per subject, you have to use `GROUP BY ?s` and use a subselect (which checks the restriction on the number of properties for a subject) combined with a simple pattern match.

**EDIT** Note that I slightly modified your original update: it's inserting into a *different* named graph from the one that you are querying. Inserting into the same named graph will of course work, but the results will not be observable (as you are just inserting the same data that was already present in that graph).

Comment: This query is not working in my local Jena Fuseki. Only is working the INSERT DATA, but not the whole query.

Comment: First of all, "it's not working" is not a problem description. What do you see, and what did you expect? I do note that the inline comments I added here for clarification aren't valid, I forgot SPARQL uses # instead of //. I tested the operation in RDF4J where it works fine. Of course, the _result_ of this operation will be nothing, as you are retrieving data from and inserting data into the same named graph. If you want to observe results, you will have to change the target named graph into something else. I've updated my answer to show this.