# sparql "diff" (minus with some unshared variables)

Tags: sparql

This is a followup on my question [Compare models for identity, but with variables? Construct with minus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724693/compare-models-for-identity-but-with-variables-construct-with-minus). Either I forgot what I learned then, or I didn't learn as much as I has thought.

I have triples like this:

```
prefix : <http://example.com/>

:rose :color :red .
:violet :color :blue .
:rose a :flower .
:flower rdfs:subClassOf :plant .
:dogs :love :trucks .
```

I want to discover any triples in my triplestore that don't satisfy at least one of **these rules**:

1. take `:rose` as the *subject*
2. take `:rose`'s parent class as the *subject*
3. use any of the *predicates* that are used in any triple with `:rose` as the *subject*
4. take, as their *object*, the *object* of any triple with `:rose` as the *subject*.

Thus, in this case, the exception-discovery query (either select or construct) should only return

```
:dogs :love :trucks .
```

This query shows what **should** be in the triplestore:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.com/>
construct where {
    :rose ?p ?o  .
    :rose a ?c .
    ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?super .
    ?s ?p ?x1 .
    ?x2 ?x3 ?o
}
```

.

```
+---+---------+-----------------+---------+
|   | subject |    predicate    | object  |
+---+---------+-----------------+---------+
| A | :flower | rdfs:subClassOf | :plant  |
| B | :rose   | :color          | :red    |
| C | :rose   | rdf:type        | :flower |
| D | :violet | :color          | :blue   |
+---+---------+-----------------+---------+
```

Is there a way to subtract that pattern out of everything in the triplestore, `{ ?s ?p ?o }`, even though I'm using variable names other than `?s`, `?p` and `?o` in the `construct` statement?

I have seen [this post](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/How_to_diff_RDF) with strategies for comparing RDF, but I'd like to do it with standard SPARQL.

To tie it together with my earlier post, this final query erroneously suggests that several desired triples violate the **rules** set out at the top of the message.

```
   +---------+-----------------+---------+
 E | :dogs   | :love           | :trucks |
 A | :flower | rdfs:subClassOf | :plant  |
 D | :violet | :color          | :blue   |
   +---------+-----------------+---------+
```

Triple E is indeed undesired.  But A is desired because it has `:rose`'s *class* as its *subject* (**rule 2**), and triple D is desired because it's *predicate* is also used in some triples with :rose as the *subject*  (**rule 3**).

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/>
CONSTRUCT 
  { 
    ?s ?p ?o .
  }
WHERE
  { SELECT  ?s ?p ?o
    WHERE
      { { ?s  ?p  ?o }
        MINUS
          { :rose  ?p               ?o ;
                   rdf:type         ?c .
            ?c     rdfs:subClassOf  ?super .
            ?s     ?p               ?x1 .
            ?x2    ?x3              ?o
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? "if my triplestore contains any triples that violate these rules: 1. aren't about :rose 2 ..."  Is the rule that triples *should* be about rose (and by this, do you mean "rose is the subject" or "rose is the subject or object (or predicate)"), or that they shouldn't?  It's usually not too hard to write SPARQL queries that find violations of some rules, but it needs to be clear what the rules **are**.

Comment: Thanks.  I was working on that vague section when you posted!  Is it better now?  I have more examples of **undesired behavior** at the bottom no, too.

Comment: The problem is that the `MINUS` forms (as usual) a set of solution sequences and not a set of triples. And indeed it won't work to subtract it especially since you don't have shared variables, but here it's more critical that you're not subtracting triples inside a SELECT query.

Comment: "I want to any triples in my triplestore that don't satisfy…"?  Maybe you want to _delete_ those?

Comment: @TallTed  thanks.  no, I just want to know what they are for now.

Comment: Clarified by the edited sentence.

Comment: I was going to reword your rules to match your text ... but then I got confused about rule #2, "say something about the parent(s) of `:rose`'s _class_" which you later describe as satisfied by a triple that "has `:rose`'s _class_ as its object" (which object is actually `:rose`'s class's _parent_). Clarity and consistency are vital here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to *allow* four types of triples in your data.   If a triple (s,p,o) is in your data, it should satisfy at least one of the following criteria:

1. s = rose **(About rose)**
2. p = rdfs:subClassOf, and data contains (rose,a,s) **(About a type)**
3. The data also contains (rose,p,x) **(Shared predicate)**
4. The data also contains (rose,q,o) **(Shared object)**

It's easy enough to write a pattern for each one of those.  You just need to find each triple (s,p,o) and filter out the ones that match none of those criteria.  I think you can do it like this:

```sql
select ?s ?p ?o {
  ?s ?p ?o 
  filter not exists {
          { values ?s { :rose } }                       #-- (1)
    union { values ?p { rdfs:subClassOf } :rose a ?s }  #-- (2)
    union { :rose ?p ?x }                               #-- (3)
    union { :rose ?x ?o }                               #-- (4)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed a correct answer :D Works for me (tested with Stardog 5.x): `(s,p,o): (:flower, rdfs:subClassOf, :plant)  | (:dogs, :love, :trucks)` Indeed generating this kind of query automatically might be more difficult, but I guess that was not the question here. Cheers!

Comment: **Works as requested in Blazegraph 2.1.1.**  *Returns 0 triples in GraphDB Free 8.2.0.*

Comment: Maybe GraphDB has some issues with the `VALUES` inside a `FILTER NOT EXISTS`, which is rarely used in combination - but who knows.

Comment: @MarkMiller Definitely report that to BlazeGraph.  My query could be wrong, of course, but the change in behavior means that one of the versions is buggy.  Instead of `values ?s { :rose }`, you can use `filter (?s = :rose)` or `filter sameTerm(?s,:rose)` of course (and similarly for case (2)).