# SPARQL insert containing expression

Tags: sparql, rdf

I would like to insert triple patterns like this into a Sesame endpoint, but I just can't seem to pull it all together

```
bind(UUID() as ?uuid) .
bind(now() as ?timeVal) .
:event1 :hasUuid ?uuid.
:event1 :hasTimestamp ?timeVal
```

- [Virtuoso seems to have a propriety way of doing it](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksGuideExpressionsUsageInConstructInsertDelete)
- [It seems like a similar issue is addressed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575837/it-is-possible-to-use-aggregate-function-when-inserting-data-in-sparql)
- @AKSW gave some good advice for [doing something similar in a `construct` query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724693/compare-models-for-identity-but-with-variables-construct-with-minus)

Comment: In general, for any non-`SELECT`query you can keep in mind that anything beyond simple graph pattern has to be put in `SELECT` queries.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Sesame/RDF4J, but the following works with Jena ARQ:

```
INSERT
  { 
  :event1 :hasUuid ?uuid .
  :event1 :hasTimestamp ?timeVal .
  }
WHERE
  { SELECT ?uuid ?timeVal
    WHERE
      {
      BIND(UUID() AS ?uuid) .
      BIND(now() AS ?timeVal) .
      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes that is the standards compliant approach